# Xamarin.Forms: How to display database data to an OxyPlot Chart?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, oxyplot

I'm creating a Xamarin.Forms Portable Application wherein I was able to display a Pie Chart using OxyPlot. My chart only has pre-defined items. What I want to do is to make the items from my **DATABASE** in Visual Studio to be displayed on the Chart and not the pre-defined items.

I created a SalesController where I used LINQ expression to get all the data in the database that I need. In my Web Forms project.

In my PORTABLE project, I have a Sales model and a PieViewModel where I declare my Pie Chart. What do I need to do to my SalesViewModel for it to be able to display the retrieved data to my Chart? I'm just a newbie in using OxyPlot so maybe you can help me.

Here are my codes:

**WebForms**

**1.)** SalesViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebFormsDemo.ViewModel
{
    public class SalesViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ORDER_ID { get; set; }
        public int ORDER_DETAILS_ID { get; set; }
        public int PRODUCT_ID { get; set; }
        public string PRODUCT_CODE { get; set; }
        public string NET_AMOUNT { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**2.)** SalesController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using WebFormsDemo;
using WebFormsDemo.ViewModel;

namespace WebFormsDemo.Controllers
{
public class SalesController : ApiController
{
    private EBMSEntities db = new EBMSEntities();

    // GET: api/Sales
    public IQueryable<SalesViewModel> GetSalesViewModels()
    {
        //return db.SalesViewModels;
        var sales = from order in db.ORDERs
                    join order_detail in db.ORDER_DETAILS
                    on order.ORDER_ID equals order_detail.ORDER_ID
                    join prod in db.PRODUCTs
                    on order_detail.PRODUCT_ID equals prod.PRODUCT_ID
                    orderby order_detail.TOTAL_AMT_PER_ITEM descending
                    //group prod by prod.PRODUCT_CODE
                    group order_detail by prod.PRODUCT_CODE into od
                    select new SalesViewModel
                    {

                        PRODUCT_CODE = od.Key,
                        NET_AMOUNT = od.Sum(p => p.TOTAL_AMT_PER_ITEM).ToString(),

                    };

        return sales;


    }

    // GET: api/Sales/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(SalesViewModel))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetSalesViewModel(int id)
    {
        SalesViewModel salesViewModel = db.SalesViewModels.Find(id);
        if (salesViewModel == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(salesViewModel);
    }

    // PUT: api/Sales/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutSalesViewModel(int id, SalesViewModel salesViewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != salesViewModel.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(salesViewModel).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!SalesViewModelExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST: api/Sales
    [ResponseType(typeof(SalesViewModel))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostSalesViewModel(SalesViewModel salesViewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.SalesViewModels.Add(salesViewModel);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = salesViewModel.Id }, salesViewModel);
    }

    // DELETE: api/Sales/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(SalesViewModel))]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteSalesViewModel(int id)
    {
        SalesViewModel salesViewModel = db.SalesViewModels.Find(id);
        if (salesViewModel == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.SalesViewModels.Remove(salesViewModel);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(salesViewModel);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool SalesViewModelExists(int id)
    {
        return db.SalesViewModels.Count(e => e.Id == id) > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

.

**XamarinFormsPortable**

**1.)** Sales.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace XamarinFormsDemo.Models
    {
    public class Sales
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ORDER_ID { get; set; }
        public int ORDER_DETAILS_ID { get; set; }
        public int PRODUCT_ID { get; set; }
        public string PRODUCT_CODE { get; set; }
        public string NET_AMOUNT { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**2.)** SalesVM - I don't have codes for SalesVM yet.